# Compare DateTime objects by their dates

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I hope someone can help me that knows Joda Time pretty well.  Here is the code:

```
DateTimeComparator comparator = DateTimeComparator.getInstance(
    DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth(), DateTimeFieldType.year());

java.sql.Date beforeDate = new java.sql.Date(1372910400000L);  // July 4 2013
java.sql.Date nowDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
DateTime beforeDateTime = new DateTime(beforeDate);
DateTime nowDateTime = new DateTime(nowDate);

int result = comparator.compare(nowDateTime, beforeDateTime);
System.out.println(nowDate+" compared to "+beforeDate+" = "+result);
```

> ```
> 2015-03-15 compared to 2013-07-04 = -1
> ```

From the Javadocs API for compare:

> Returns:
>       zero if order does not matter, negative value if lhsObj < rhsObj, positive value otherwise.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're excluding the year from comparison, which makes it 03/15 is less than 07/04.
From `getInstance(DateTimeFieldType lowerLimit,DateTimeFieldType upperLimit)`

> Returns a DateTimeComparator with a lower and upper limit. Fields of a
>   magnitude less than the lower limit are excluded from comparisons.
>   Fields of a magnitude greater than **or equal** to the upper limit are
>   also excluded from comparisons. Either limit may be specified as null,
>   which indicates an unbounded limit.

Comment: That explains it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given your current code sample, you want to pass `null` as the upper bound for the `DateTimeComparator` to properly compare `DateTime` objects by date:

```
DateTimeComparator.getInstance(DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth(), null);
```

This says "Compare `DateTime` objects on the basis of the day of the month, and everything broader than that, treating more precise fields like time as equal".

---

But really, this isn't what you want to do with JodaTime at all.  JodaTime provides a number of different date and time classes for different operations, and if your goal is to compare dates, you want to use [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html).  Its `.compareTo()` works exactly as you'd expect:

```
new LocalDate().compareTo(new LocalDate(2013,7,4)) // returns 1
```

Notice that `java.sql.Date` only stores date information, not time or timezone information.  By constructing a `DateTime` object, you artificially associate a time and timezone with what was just a date.  `java.sql.Date`'s proper sibling in Joda-Time is `LocalDate`.

When you care about dates, use `LocalDate`, when you care about times, use [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html), when you care about times on a given day, use [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html).  What these classes all have in common is they represent our abstract notions of time, *not* an instant in history.  This might seem strange, but it's often what you really want.  The key-concepts documentation on [partials](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_partial.html) goes into some detail about this.

Only when you actually need to talk about instants in real-time should you use `DateTime` and its related classes.  This is actually not as common as you might think with date/time-heavy code.  Start with the `Local*` classes, and see if they can fulfill your use case.